# discord.js bot prefix with a space?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, prefix

How would you go about using a space in your bots prefix? for example, like how dank memer would use "pls rob" I tried using a space where I define my prefix, but that does not work.

Comment: Please include what you've tried, and any errors it may have given you.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you've tried, but it works for me.

`const prefix = 'something '`

```
if (msg.content === prefix+'w') {
    msg.reply('yes');
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is Command Handler**

It is Not in One file You can also make like that Only Use Command Handlers

Make
const prefix = ('pls');

then make

command handler make new files rob.js

***It will work***

If you don't known command handler

Here is Way to Make Command Handler
: => https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/

Comment: its not the best idea to answer bad questions.